# Unable to Read JSON file using Elephant Bird

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-pig

Trying to load the json file which is having null values in it by using **elephant-bird JsonLoader**.

**sample.json**

```
{"created_at": "Mon Aug 22 10:48:23 +0000 2016","id": 767674772662607873,"id_str": "767674772662607873","text": "KPIT Image Result for https:\/\/t.co\/Nas2ZnF1zZ... https:\/\/t.co\/9TnelwtIvm","source": "\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter Web Client\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated": false,"in_reply_to_status_id": 123,"in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,"in_reply_to_user_id": null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,"in_reply_to_screen_name": null,"geo": null,"coordinates": null,"place": null,"contributors": null,"is_quote_status": false,"retweet_count": 0,"favorite_count": 0,"entities": {"hashtags": [],"urls": [{"url": "https:\/\/t.co\/Nas2ZnF1zZ","expanded_url": "http:\/\/miltonious.com\/","display_url": "miltonious.com","indices": [24, 47]}],"user_mentions": [],"symbols": []},"favorited": false,"retweeted": false,"possibly_sensitive": false,"filter_level": "low","lang": "en","timestamp_ms": "1471862903167"}
```

**script:**

```
REGISTER piggybank.jar
REGISTER json-simple-1.1.1.jar
REGISTER elephant-bird-pig-4.3.jar
REGISTER elephant-bird-core-4.1.jar
REGISTER elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.3.jar

json = LOAD 'sample.json' USING JsonLoader('created_at:chararray, id:chararray, id_str:chararray, text:chararray, source:chararray, in_reply_to_status_id:chararray, in_reply_to_status_id_str:chararray, in_reply_to_user_id:chararray, in_reply_to_user_id_str:chararray, in_reply_to_screen_name:chararray, geo:chararray, coordinates:chararray, place:chararray, contributors:chararray, is_quote_status:bytearray, retweet_count:long, favorite_count:chararray, entities:map[], favorited:bytearray, retweeted:bytearray, possibly_sensitive:bytearray, lang:chararray');

describe json;
dump json;
```

When I dump json,I am getting the following **output** and the **worning**

**(Mon Aug 22 10:48:23 +0000    2016,767674772662607873,767674772662607873,google Image Result for Twitter Web    Client,false,1234,12345,3214,43215,,,,,,,,,,,,,,)**

**WARN org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigHadoopLogger - org.apache.pig.builtin.JsonLoader(UDF_WARNING_1): Bad record, returning null for {complete json}**

By warning i guess it is getting NULL values.
So how can we load a Json which is having null values in it.

And I have tried in another way i.e

```
json = LOAD 'sample.json' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('created_at:chararray, id:chararray, id_str:chararray, text:chararray, source:chararray, in_reply_to_status_id:chararray, in_reply_to_status_id_str:chararray, in_reply_to_user_id:chararray, in_reply_to_user_id_str:chararray, in_reply_to_screen_name:chararray, geo:chararray, coordinates:chararray, place:chararray, contributors:chararray, is_quote_status:bytearray, retweet_count:long, favorite_count:chararray, entities:map[], favorited:bytearray, retweeted:bytearray, possibly_sensitive:bytearray, lang:chararray');

describe json;
```

**Output**

```
Schema for json unknown.
```

Please suggest me.

Thanks.

Comment: does the avro(.AVSC) schema definition file exist in the same directory ? I think it is not present from your above error !

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Sandesh. No it is not.Is it mandatory?...If yes then can you please suggest me to get the file..It will be soo helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this,

```
 MY_JSON = LOAD 'sample.json' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad');
 dump MY_JSON;
```